# Pdf download in android webview

Tags: php, android-studio

I've linked my website developed in php in android via webview. The problem i'm facing is when i try to download a pdf file it takes the name of php page not the pdf document which is to be downloaded. Can anybody please help???

Answer (score 0):

You can supply the suggested filename with a `Content-Disposition` header:

```
header("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename='Yourfile.pdf'");
```

Make sure the header is sent before the filed is passed to the client.

Comment: The file is getting downloaded when i give a static filename like myfile.pdf but, when i try to fetch the filename of the pdf file dynamically it is getting downloaded but it takes the filename of the php page